# Area enclosed between $\min(|x|,|y|)\ge1$and $x^2+y^2 \le5$

Tags: area, curves

The area of the region included between the regions satisfying $$\min(|x|,|y|)\ge1$$ and $$x^2+y^2 \le5$$  is ______

I am unable to construct the curve $\min(|x|,|y|)\ge1$ hence cannot proceed.

Comment: The curve is a "plus sign" around the origin (the inequality gives everything outside of it)

Comment: HINT: $\min \{ a,b \} \ge 1$ means that both $a$ and $b$ must be $\ge 1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $$|x|\geq |y|$$ then $$\min(|x|,|y|)=|y|$$ and
if $$|x|<|y|$$ then $$\min(|x|,|y|)=|x|$$